# How to create a varchar(max) field in ADOX in VB6

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ado, adox

Using VB6, MSSqlServer and ADOX, I need to create a field to store large text, and to use varchar (MAX).

A [DefinedSize] property of ADOX is long.

I would like to know how to set this field to varchar(max) on create.

A exemple of my code:

```
Case "dbText", "10"
    coluna.Type = adVarChar
    coluna.DefinedSize = HERE I DON'T KNOW
```

Comment: the max data type didn't exist at the time that VB6 was in its prime, so there is not a direct conversion. There may be some hacky workarounds...

Comment: You won't be able to do this with ADOX, as @Jeremy points out.  You could craft and execute a DDL query to create the object(s).

Comment: ADOX is a Jet-oriented library.  I doubt it can do much at all with SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I walked around this using query to create this field.
Thanks you all.